# How to find (nxx) for 40 millions?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to find the number of all possible strings in the following form:

$ (nxx)-nxx-xxxx$ , where $n =1...9 $and $x = 0...9$

### My trying :

Actually I cant find any clue to solve this problem . This question came from previous year question of discrete mathematics .

Comment: What? What is the objective? Guess a telephone number?

Comment: Yes , it may be USA mobile no

Comment: You do not give a definition of what you want to find....

Comment: Do you need to know the number of combinations?

Comment: Yes @dmtri . I actually want to find that

Comment: Okay, then say that. Say that you want to find the total number of possible telephone numbers. As written, your question does not say this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Each $n$ can be chosen in 9 different ways and each $x$ can be chosen in 10 different ways. All choices are independent. So the total number of choices is:

$$(9\times10\times10)\times(9\times10\times10)\times(10\times10\times10\times10)=8.1\times10^{9}$$